# Make Spring RabbitMQ fail on missing exchange

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

There is nice property `spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.missing-queues-fatal=true`
it makes SimpleMessageListenerContainer and whole application fail when I set it a non existent queue - which is what I want. I don't want to have an application running in invalid state.

I can't find similar solution for exchanges like

spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.missing-**exchanges**-fatal

I get in logs several

```
ERROR 432430 --- [ 127.0.0.1:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Shutdown Signal: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'some-non-existent-exchange' in vhost '/', class-id=40, method-id=30)
```

and application starts. I would like it to fail. How can I do it?

How can I make spring boot/rabbit fail when trying to bind to any of non existing queue or exchange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exchange does nothing with listener. We need it along side with a routing key when we produce data into AMQP. The listener has that option to fail because it is out of end-user control and starts automatically when application is ready. The exchange is used in the `RabbitTemplate` when you send a data. See `publisherReturns` option on the `CachingConnectionFactory` for use-case like yours to handle such an error in case of missed exchange:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#cf-pub-conf-ret
https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html

You also add a `ReturnsCallback` into your `RabbitTemplate` to catch an unrouted message and its reason and handle such an error respectively: in your case stop the app, e.g. `System.exit(1);`.

Comment: Thx for reply, I will study it. How would you find idea of creating a subclass of Binding which would validate in constructor with some rabbitAdminTemplate if its queue and exchange params exists? I would like to stop my app earlier, on boot time. RabbitTemplate can be used much later.

Comment: It is not a Binding responsibility to do that. You probably can use a RabbitMQ REST API to check for entities on the broker: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#management-rest-api

Comment: You can attempt to passively declare the exchange in an `ApplicationRunner` bean - if the exchange doesn't exist, throw an exception. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201931/check-if-the-exchange-with-a-specified-name-exist-in-rabbitmq/25204215#25204215

Comment: Thx for help. Could you please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70212347/rabbitmq-cachingconnectionfactory-and-publisherreturns-configuration