# RabbitMQ CachingConnectionFactory and publisherReturns configuration

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

A continuation of [Make Spring RabbitMQ fail on missing exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70184352/make-spring-rabbitmq-fail-on-missing-exchange)

I register MessageListenerContainer for multiple queues.

Where and how should I configure channel returnListener? - I thing the way I have done it is wrong. I inserted CachingConnectionFactory **configuration** into create**QueueB**MessageListener(...) - method responsible for creating one of multiple MessageListeners.

**1. How should be CachingConnectionFactory additional configuration done Spring and Rabbit way?** By now I didn't configure it in Java (only by application.properties and admins in K8S environment). I only injected ConnectionFactory and set it as connectionFactory in SimpleMessageListenerContainer (as in createQueueAMessageListener(...)), I even didn't know it's CachingConnectionFactory.

Is there something like CachingConnectionFactoryConfigurer?

**2. Why is ReturnListener.handleReturn(..) not executed?** ChannelListener.onCreate(...) is executed.

**3.  Checking missing exchange exception in cachingConnectionFactory.setCloseExceptionLogger and doing System.exit(1) there seems wrong to me, isn't it?** But this is all I managed to do by now. I want to application not start when there is no exchange during binding creation. When I throw exception there application still starts. ReturnListener.handleReturn seems a better place for it, but it isn't executed when configured as below.

**4.  How can I stop Spring Application Context gracefully instead of System.exit(1)?** - throwing exception doesn't stop Application Context. How to make RabbitMq fail to start in such situation? - when a creation of @Bean Binding at Spring Application Context start fails.

```
@Bean
MessageListenerContainer createQueueAMessageListener(SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory,
                                                   ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = rabbitListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames("queueA");
    MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = null;
    container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(new Object(), jsonMessageConverter));

    return container;
}

@Bean
MessageListenerContainer createQueueBMessageListener(SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory,
                                                     ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                     CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory) {

    // I think configuring CachingConnectionFactory here is a lame, isn't it? Of course connectionFactory is redundant now, I left it to show how was it done earlier.
    // Where and how should I add listeners to CachingConnectionFactory?

    cachingConnectionFactory.setPublisherConfirmType(CachingConnectionFactory.ConfirmType.CORRELATED);
    cachingConnectionFactory.setPublisherReturns(true);
    cachingConnectionFactory.addChannelListener(new ChannelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Channel channel, final boolean transactional) {

            log.info("channelListener onCreate - this is executed");

            channel.addReturnListener(new ReturnListener() {
                @Override
                public void handleReturn(final int replyCode, final String replyText, final String exchange, final String routingKey,
                                         final AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                                         final byte[] body) throws IOException
                {
                    log.info("!!! Why is this not executed ?!!! handleReturn replyCode: " + replyCode + " replyText: " + replyText);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    cachingConnectionFactory.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Connection connection) {
            log.info("connectionListener onCreate - this is executed" + connection);
        }
    });

    cachingConnectionFactory.setCloseExceptionLogger(new ConditionalExceptionLogger() {
        @Override
        public void log(final Log logger, final String message, final Throwable t) {
            try {
                logger.error(message + ": " + t.getMessage());
                if (t.getMessage().contains("reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND")) {
                    // throw new RuntimeException(); it doesn't stop Spring ApplicationContext from starting
                    log.error("Executing System.exit(1) command.");
                    // System.exit(1);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("err in listener ", e);
            }
           
        }
    });


    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = rabbitListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames("queueB");
    MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = null;
    container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(new Object(), jsonMessageConverter));

    return container;
}

@Bean
MessageListenerContainer createQueueCMessageListener(SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory,
                                                     ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = rabbitListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames("queueC");
    MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = null;
    container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(new Object(), jsonMessageConverter));

    return container;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 

> // I think configuring CachingConnectionFactory here is a lame, isn't it?

It is not "lame"; that is the normal way of configuring beans with additional properties not exposed directly by Boot.

2. It **should** be called; have you tried debugging?
3. Why don't you do what I advised here [Make Spring RabbitMQ fail on missing exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70184352/make-spring-rabbitmq-fail-on-missing-exchange/70186230#comment124099127_70186230) - it's much simpler.
4. `close()` it - but, since you are using Spring Boot, it will do that for you - it registers a JVM shutdown hook that closes the context.

**EDIT**

Binding to a non-existent exchange will fail; you just need to force it to happen before the application is fully initialized, e.g. in an `ApplicationRunner`.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So70212347Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So70212347Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding() {
        return new Binding("foo", DestinationType.QUEUE, "doesn't exist", "foo", null);
    }

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("foo");
    }


    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        return args -> {
            cf.createConnection().close();
        };
    }

}
```

```
Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#6a0cbc6f:0/SimpleConnection@6cd164a6 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 62884]
Shutdown Signal: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'doesn't exist' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=20)
Shutdown Signal: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'doesn't exist' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=20)
Shutdown Signal: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'doesn't exist' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=20)
Shutdown Signal: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'doesn't exist' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=20)
Shutdown Signal: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'doesn't exist' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=20)


Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:748)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:309)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290)
    at com.example.demo.So70212347Application.main(So70212347Application.java:16)
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:70)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitAccessor.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitAccessor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2192)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2138)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2118)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.initialize(RabbitAdmin.java:691)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.lambda$null$10(RabbitAdmin.java:619)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:209)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$11(RabbitAdmin.java:618)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CompositeConnectionListener.lambda$onCreate$0(CompositeConnectionListener.java:38)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.forEach(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:807)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CompositeConnectionListener.onCreate(CompositeConnectionListener.java:38)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:730)
    at com.example.demo.So70212347Application.lambda$0(So70212347Application.java:33)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:758)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:129)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:125)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:147)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueBind(ChannelN.java:1077)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueBind(ChannelN.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1157)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.queueBind(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.declareBindings(RabbitAdmin.java:870)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.lambda$initialize$12(RabbitAdmin.java:694)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.invokeAction(RabbitTemplate.java:2227)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2186)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'doesn't exist' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=20)
...
```

Comment: Thx for clarification. Yes, I did as you advised https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201931/check-if-the-exchange-with-a-specified-name-exist-in-rabbitmq/25204215#25204215 - and it worked, thx. Solution with listener would be more automatic, configured in one place would work for all missing exchanges. Now I have to check every single exchange before binding. I did some debugging, but I didn't spot anything obvious, I just thought I did something wrong.

Comment: As I said on GitHub, the framework has no idea what exchanges an application might use, so it's hard to see how it can check on your behalf.

Comment: I just thought that the moment of binding creation could be appropriate - when binding on nonexisting exchange fails. Especially when this @Bean Binding is created at application context startup.

Comment: When binding to a non-existent exchange (rather than sending), the `RabbitAdmin` will throw an exception when retries are exhausted - you just need to open a connection earlier, e.g. in an `ApplicationRunner` `@Bean`; that way, the exception will propagate to the Boot startup; I'll add an edit to my answer.