# Check if binding exists

Tags: java, binding, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, messagebroker

I would like to check if a certain binding exists on a queue or an exchange in a Spring application. I can only find information about [checking if an *exchange* exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201931/check-if-the-exchange-with-a-specified-name-exist-in-rabbitmq).

or a *queue*: `RabbitAdmin.java`

I'm using the following dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.6</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it over the AMQP protocol; you can use the RabbitMQ REST API.

They have a Java binding for it:

https://github.com/rabbitmq/hop