# Spring AMQP - Publish to a Non-Existent Exchange Exception Handling

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm attempting to account for a scenario where my `Publisher` publishes to a `DirectExchange` that doesn't exist.

According to the [spring-amqp documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.3.9/reference/html/#publishing-is-async), I should be able to use `rabbitTemplate.setChannelTransacted(true)` in order for this exception to be thrown:

> To detect the exception on the sending thread, you can setChannelTransacted(true) on the RabbitTemplate and the exception is detected on the txCommit(). However, transactions significantly impede performance, so consider this carefully before enabling transactions for just this one use case.

Currently, the above config only throws the exception in the event that my `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend` is *not* wrapped in a `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` method, otherwise I just get an error logged silently with no exception thrown.

Ideally, I need my method which publish messages to perform database work prior to publishing, which requires me to wrap it in a `@Transactional`. Is this possible? I'm thinking I might have a misconfiguration somewhere preventing this from working as I would expect.

Here is my `rabbitTemplate` configuration:

```java
    @Bean
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setReturnsCallback(new ReturnsCallback() {
            
            @Override
            public void returnedMessage(ReturnedMessage returned) {
                //routingKey doesn't exist, notify and send to parking lot...
            }
        });
        rabbitTemplate.setMandatory(true);
        rabbitTemplate.setChannelTransacted(true);
        rabbitTemplate.setExchange("some.exchange");
        
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
```

Here is my publish:

```java
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void publishMessage() {
        
        // database processing...
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("myRoutingKey", "myMessage");
    }
```

Again, `some.exchange` does not exist, and `publishMessage()` is wrapped in a `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`, the output is a silent error logged:

```
ERROR o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory [AbstractConnectionFactory.java:748] Shutdown Signal: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'some.exchange' in vhost '/consume', class-id=60, method-id=40)
```

If I modify my publish and remove `@Transactional`, I will get the exception I'm looking for on `txCommit()`:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitUtils.commitIfNecessary(RabbitUtils.java:144)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doSend(RabbitTemplate.java:2398)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.lambda$send$3(RabbitTemplate.java:1064)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.invokeAction(RabbitTemplate.java:2229)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2188)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2140)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:1063)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1128)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1110)
        at gov.osc.lgmm.service.core.impl.CoreServiceImpl.sendFilingStatus(CoreServiceImpl.java:120)
        ... 75 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:129)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:125)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:147)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.txCommit(ChannelN.java:1540)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.txCommit(ChannelN.java:46)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.txCommit(PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java:633)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1157)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy185.txCommit(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitUtils.commitIfNecessary(RabbitUtils.java:141)
        ... 84 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'some.exchange' in vhost '/consume', class-id=60, method-id=40)
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:502)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:293)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:141)
        ... 94 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'some.exchange' in vhost '/consume', class-id=60, method-id=40)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:517)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:341)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:182)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:114)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:739)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:666)
        ... 1 common frames omitted
```

I would have expected the above exception to be thrown when my `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend` is wrapped in the `@Transactional`. Is the behavior that I'm experiencing expected, or is it likely that I have a misconfiguration somewhere?

I'm currently configured with `spring-boot 2.5.2` / `spring-amqp 2.3.9` and my transaction manager is a `JpaTransactionManager`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1362

When synchronizing with a primary transaction, commits (after the primary commit) are simply logged (by Spring transaction support) and are not thrown to the caller.

In Spring AMQP 2.4.x, we added a mechanism so you can check the success/failure of the secondary (rabbit commit) and make a compensating transaction (if necessary) to back out the committed DB transaction:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#tx-sync

Boot 2.5.x (and 2.6.x) is no longer supported as OSS (https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support).

Spring AMQP 2.4.x is compatible with Boot 2.6.x and 2.7.x.

**EDIT**

You can also enable publisher confirms to check whether the message was ack'd (and not returned due to no route to a queue).

```java
CorrelationData corr = new CorrelationData();
template.convertAndSend("junk", "", "foo", corr);
CompletableFuture<Confirm> future = corr.getFuture();
Confirm confirm = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println(confirm + " ret:" + corr.getReturned());
```

```
Confirm [ack=false, reason=channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'junk' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)] ret:null
```

Note that you don't get a returned message when routing to a non-existent exchange. When the exchange is present, but there is no route, `ack` will be true, but the returned message will be populated.

Also note that 3.0.x and later use a `CompletableFuture`; earlier versions used a Spring `ListenableFuture`.

Confirms cannot be used on transactional channels, however, so this is probably not what you want because the publish won't roll back if the DB commit fails.

Comment: You can also use publisher confirms to check the status; I added an example.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of the information. I did consider using `CorrelationData` combined with `rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback`, but I can't set a publisher confirm type in my `CachingConnectionFactory` if I have channel transacted set to true. Is it okay if I use a confirmCallback with channel transacted set to true?

Comment: It's now preferred to use the future in the correlation data rather than using the async callback on the template. Right; I meant you can use a confirm instead of a transaction; that way you will get immediate feedback. On the other hand, the publish will not roll back if the DB transaction is rolled back, so that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Yes, I am using transacted true mainly to account for exceptions with DB processing, and was hoping I could also cover the scenario described above. So at this point I'm afraid I can't opt for confirms instead of transactions.

Comment: Just so I understand my path moving forward, my options are: 1) Upgrade Spring AMQP to 2.4.x to accomplish what I'm trying above, or 2) Use confirm instead of transaction and use the future (not recommended if I need transactional rollbacks). One other option I've been thinking about would be setting transacted to true, providing CorrelationData with my message pre-populated, and having a confirmCallback where I can send the correlation data message to a parking-lot queue in the event that the exchange doesn't exist. Would something like that be valid or would that be considered bad practice?

Comment: If you want to get off unsupported code, I would recommend upgrading. I don't see why your solution won't work, but you'll need to save the output data in the correlation data because there is no returned message with a missing exchange. You could also check that the exchange exists first - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201931/check-if-the-exchange-with-a-specified-name-exist-in-rabbitmq/25204215#25204215